# Prove there is infinite number of 3 consecutive numbers which are sum of 2 squares.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, constructive-mathematics

> Prove there is infinite number of 3 consecutive numbers which are sum of 2 squares of ($0\notin $) natural numbers. Example: $$72 = 6^2+6^2$$
> $$73= 8^2+3^2$$
> $$74 =7^2+5^2$$

I could only find 232,233 and 234 is next such triple. I was also thinking about to implement $$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc) ^2$$ but don't know how.

Comment: Do you allow for $0^2$?

Comment: Other such triples begin with $520, 800, 1096, 1312, 2312, 2600$. Having calculated these, I can find no simple pattern to describe them, but they are certainly much more frequent than the families described in Calvin Lin's answer.

Comment: Look for three consecutive number in OEIS sequence *sum of two squares* https://oeis.org/A001481 e.g. a triple not listed here yet and taken from that sequence is $80, 81, 82.$ (Or, $16+64,0+81,1+81$, doesn't quite qualify as $0$ is one of the summands, but seems the sequence is relevant anyway.) But, also look at https://oeis.org/A082982 *Numbers $n$ such that $n, n+1$ and $n+2$ are sums of $2$ squares* (again, $0$ is allowed as a summand).

Comment: In one of the answers posted, the third of the consecutive numbers is of the form $n^2+1.$ In another answer posted, the second of the consecutive numbers is of the form $m^2+1.$ The example in the question does not involve $1$ as a summand. So one may ask your question with the additional restriction that in the sums of two squares the number $1$ is never used as a summand. Are there infinitely many such triples? What if we also pick any positive integer $k$ and require that in the representations $x^2+y^2$ we always have $x>k$ and $y>k$? Are there infinitely many triples for each fixed $k$?

Comment: @Mirko I believe the answer to your constrained question is also yes for each $k$, though the construction produces an exponentially growing sequence.  In my thesis I constructed infinitely many *quintuples* in certain binary quadratic forms, and it seems likely we can trade off the extra two terms to force $k$ to be unbounded.

Comment: @Mirko I don’t seem to have the paper handy, but Hooley showed (by methods more arithmetic than analytic  I think) that the sums of two squares contain infinitely many copies of any $3$-term constellation you wish ($n,n+h,n+k$).  Such methods might also yield an affirmative answer since they seem less likely to rely on special values like $n^2+1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we have a solution where $ n-1 = a^2 + b^2, n = c^2 + d^2, n+1 = e^2 + f^2 $, with all variables non-zero, then

- $n$ has to be odd, because $\{n-1, n, n+1\} \equiv \{0, 1, 2\} \pmod{4}$.
- $n^2 -1 = (ae+bf)^2 + (af - be)^2$  -> If either of these are 0, then $n^2 = 1 + m^2$ which easily leads to a contradiction.
- $ n^2 = (c^2 - d^2)^2 + (2cd)^2$. -> Since $n$ is odd, so $ c \neq d$ and thus $c^2 - d^2 \neq 0$.
- $n^2 + 1 = n^2 + 1$.

Thus, we have our 3 consecutive integers

So, starting with your seed of $ n = 73$, an infinite family exists.

Comment: Ok, how does that help?

Comment: @Aqua To clarify, I'm still using $0^2$ for now. However, the hope from here is that $n^2$ might be written as $a^2 + b^2$ ....

Comment: But if $n=a^2+b^2$ with $a \neq b$, then $n^2=(a^2-b^2)^2+(2ab)^2$.

Comment: Ok, I didn't down vote, but I'm going to sleep now. See you tomorow.

Comment: @Mindlack Great point. And since Aqua has one such example where $a \neq b$, this works since $ n $ is never even.

Comment: Yes but does that give tree consecutive numbers?

Comment: @Aqua Yes, we get 3 consecutive numbers $n^2 -1, n^2, n^2 + 1 $, which was the point of my 2nd version of the solution (currently on 3rd version)

Comment: After all you did use the formula I mentioned

Comment: It would be interested to find all such triplets. Your recursion does not generate them.

Comment: @Aqua I think it's unlikely to find a complete classification of all such triplets, but my NT knowledge of that field is very weak. Maybe post that as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient but more messy construction.  Let $n = 50a^2 + 14a$.  Then

$$(3n)^2 + (4n)^2, \\
(5n)^2 + 1^2, \\
(3n + 8a + 1)^2 + (4n - 6a - 1)^2\\
$$

are consecutive sums of two nonzero squares.

Comment: How you found it?

Comment: Your answer seems closely related to the Pythagorean triple $(3,4,5)$. If one starts with the Pythagorean triple $(p,q,r)=(5,12,13)$ then the following is one possible solution. (I used Reduce computer algebra system to come up with, simplify and verify some solutions.) Let $n=2(1183a^2+1369a+396)$ and  $s=7a+4$. Take $(pn)^2 + (qn)^2,
(rn)^2 + 1^2,\\
(pn + 2qs + 1)^2 + (qn - 2ps - 1)^2$ For $a=0$ we get $106007616,106007617,106007618.$ $\\$ For $a=1,$ $5874915904,$5874915905,$5874915906.$ $a=2,$ $41826794256,41826794257,41826794258,$ etc. More simplification/generalization ought to work

Comment: @Aqua I thought about this question almost 30 years ago, so it was not hard to remember the general idea of the construction (two terms come “for free”, and you can hit the third target by restricting $n$ to some quadratic value).